# get records after creation using sequelize raw query

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I am using [sequelize](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize) for migration. here I execute an `INSERT` query with following options but its didnot return created records:

```
const res = oldUsers.map(u => sequelize.query(
        `INSERT INTO ${LP_LOCATIONS_TABLE} (name, address, city) 
          VALUES (
         '${u.email}', '${u.address}', '${u.city}');`,
        { type: DataTypes.QueryTypes.INSERT, raw: true },
      ))
```

the output is an array of array like below:

```
[ [[0],[1]] ]
```

i expect to get created recorders. specially PK. how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot to put `RETURNING *` at the end of the raw SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

From the [doc](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#static-method-create), you may have to specify the option `returning:true` to make this happen.  I use mySql, so can't test (the returning option is only for postgres).